# RAM capacity vs power consumption in S3 Suspend-to-RAM mode

Tags: laptop, memory, power, suspend, power-consumption

My netbook with 1GB DDR2 RAM module takes 16% of battery for 24 hours of S3 standby mode (STR - Suspend-to-RAM). That amounts to the power consumption of 0.32 Watts in standby.

That also means that the computer may easily stay in standby for *five full days* on one charge, which is quite nifty.

I assume RAM is the main electricity consumer in STR mode, so I am wondering if an upgrade to a 2GB RAM module will increase standby power consumption and consequently reduce standby time anywhere near two-fold?

**What is the relation between memory module capacity and its *standby* wattage?**

Comment: If you use a 2GB module with the same specs (timing, etc), it's the same power consumption. If you *ADD* a new module (1gb), then it's twice the amount of power you need.

Comment: How come? Doesn't each new trigger holding that extra bit of data need some nano-amperes of electricity to hold the data regardless of which IC it is on?

Comment: Enjoy: http://superuser.com/questions/40113/does-installing-larger-ram-means-consuming-more-energy

Comment: Shiki, I have seen that before posting this. The question linked by you is about active RAM power consumption. The accepted answer deals with Watts used for data transfers, not for data stored while the computer is suspended.