# How to upgrade a Sony vaio SVE1511AENB laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory, ssd

The laptop's specs are:
2 GB DDR3 RAM ( 2 slots available), 320 GB HDD, Intel i3-2328M processor.

It is 3,1/2 years old, I want to upgrade it for strictly development work (Android Studio). Here I've compiled what I should be doing:

1] Get 2 x 4GB DDR3 RAMs to utilize the 8GB limit of the system

2] Get a 250 GB Samsung 850 Evo-3D SSD

3] Throw away the CD-drive and get a caddy to hold the old 320 GB HDD.

**My questions:**

1] Will the power supply be able to work after this change?

2] SSD has lower energy consumption than HDD. Will keeping both SSD and HDD lower my battery life? (Currently it's about 2 hours every recharge cycle)

3] Can I install an MXM GPU on this motherboard (sony proprietary motherboard - data as returned by dmidecode)

Comment: SSDs use less power than HDD. See http://superuser.com/questions/40113/does-installing-larger-ram-means-consuming-more-energy for RAM. I don't think you can upgrade the GPU on that PC but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1, Yes, you are not modifying it beyond the psu design limits.

Question 2, Yes it will have a negative impact on battery life, you have added more current draw, more memory, additional SSD.

Question 3 No, the gpu is soldered onto the motherboard and the motherboard was engineered for that specific gpu that is in it currently.